# Field can be converted to a local variable ,convert field to local variable in onCreate method

Tags: java, android, xml

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView Dont_have_any_account_lets_create;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);

        Dont_have_any_account_lets_create = findViewById(R.id.Dont_have_any_account_lets_create);
        if (Dont_have_any_account_lets_create != null) {
            Dont_have_any_account_lets_create.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            });
        } else {
            Log.e("LoginActivity", "Dont_have_any_account_lets_create TextView is null");
        }
```

I am new to android developing. This is basically a login page , there is option for those having no account , so when they clicked it opens a signup form, but when i click on that button (for testing), dont have any account, the app crashes.
here in java code i am getting this error , i thought may be this  error is the main reason for that. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Which error do you get? Stacktrace please.

Comment: Did you mention SignUp in manifest file,?

Comment: Yes , i have mention there

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Stacktrace please!

Comment: Field can be converted to a local variable:19 , Typo: In word 'Dont':19 , Typo: In word 'Dont':35 , I  am new to this platform, so i dont know much about it, i can share the full code if you need? but please help me solve it

Comment: Those are no errors. You should look in the logcat instead. The stacktrace is in the logcat.

Comment: The title "Field can be converted..."  in no way is related to "the app crashes" !!?? First one is only a *suggestion*, probably because `Dont_have_any_account_lets_create` is not used somewhere else.

Comment: `there is option for those having no account ` Sorry there is nothing in your code that checks if there is an account. The only thing that is checked is if a TextView exists in the used layout.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.myfyp, PID: 21825
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfyp/com.example.myfyp.screens.SignUp}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: You should post the logcat lines in a code block in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: `NullPointerException`.

Comment: And your problem is in SignUp activity but you did not post the relevant code of it.

Comment: Please don't try to post stacktraces in comments. Edit the question instead and add it and format it as code.

Comment: thanks @blackapps , my issue has been solved. The problem was NullPointException, I was trying to set an OnClickListener on the signUp_button before initializing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First off,** please make sure when posting an issue like this, you post a stack trace so others can help you.

To get the stack trace on Android Studio, you can go to the logcat of the device you were running the app on (you don't need to be in debug mode to do this).
If you can't do it through Android studio, you can run this on your terminal (assuming you've configured your environment variables properly):

```
logcat
```

Then run the app, and get the logs for where the crash happened.

**Second** in terms of the crash that happened, the crash most likely came from the **SignUp** activity.
Make sure that the Signup Activitiy inherits from the same theme as the **LoginActivity**. If you're using AppCompatActivity you need to make sure its style inherits from a descendant of **Theme.AppCompat** (for example **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar**).

Go into your **styles.xml** and apply this theme on your Activities theme settings.

**Third**, since you're new to Android development, you should look into **Single Activity Architecture**, which is the Google Recommended architecture for new devices. It's a concept where the entire app is managed by a Single activity, and users navigate across the app via Fragments & Fragment Transactions. These transactions are managed via the Android Navigation Library:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. I am adding logcat to the question , please check it.